# AWS CodeBuild SDK, source from GitHub

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, aws-sdk, aws-codebuild

I have following use case. (Using AWS CodeBuild Node.js SDK)

I need to use a private GitHub repository as a source for CodeBuild project.

#### CASE no.1

When I go to CodeBuild project and "Edit Source" in place, I paste a personal access token and everything works as expected.

#### CASE no.2

The problem arises, when I want to achieve the very same thing, using AWS CodeBuild Node.js SDK.

I'm using the very same existing CodeBuild project and I set my `AWS.CodeBuild.start` params as following

```
{
   projectName: CODEBUILD_PROJECT,
   sourceLocationOverride: "https://github.com/owner/name",
   buildspecOverride: buildspecYML,
   sourceTypeOverride: "GITHUB",
   sourceAuthOverride: {
      // Deprecated, but TS requires it
      type: "OAUTH",
      resource: TOKEN
   }
}
```

I get response:

`InvalidInputException: No Access token found, please visit AWS CodeBuild console to connect to GitHub`

My question is. Is my use-case supported with current state of the SDK? If yes, how do I achieve it?

One thing I noticed while going through TS type definitions is the comment that only OAUTH type is currently supported. For this reason, I'm not sure if there even is a way to achieve my use-case.

```
export interface SourceAuth {
    /**
     *   This data type is deprecated and is no longer accurate or used.   The authorization type to use. The only valid value is OAUTH, which represents the OAuth authorization type.
     */
    type: SourceAuthType;
    /**
     * The resource value that applies to the specified authorization type.
     */
    resource?: String;
  }
```

#### Some more details:

What I'm trying to achieve here is building a simple CI, that will be managed from a [GitHub App](https://developer.github.com/apps/), so the token I will be passing is the users Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

With a Github source, you have two options for authType:

- OAUTH
- PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN

If using OAUTH, the only option to provide the credential is through AWS CodeBuild console. Start creating a project, under source, select 'Connect using OAuth', the click 'Connect to Github' and complete the process. You can cancel out of the Project after connecting to Github.

Confirm the credential is registered by executing the command:

```
$ aws codebuild list-source-credentials --region us-east-1
```

Output is something like:

```
{
    "sourceCredentialsInfos": [
        {
            "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:<ACCOUNTNUM>:token/github",
            "serverType": "GITHUB",
            "authType": "OAUTH"
        },
        {
            "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:<ACCOUNTNUM>:token/github_enterprise",
            "serverType": "GITHUB_ENTERPRISE",
            "authType": "PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
        }
    ]
}
```